# What are other ways of saying "to keep moving forward in times of hardship?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for another way to describe the act of forcing yourself through a s*** week

Comment: This question has garnered phrases as answers, while the duplicate did not.

Answer (score 7):

"[Soldier on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/soldier+on)": there's a slight implication that you think you're not going to make it but carry on anyway.

(idioms.thefreedictionary.com)

> to continue to do something in a determined way, esp. when you know you may not succeed.
>
> *She was working with these gorgeous guys, and she managed to soldier
>       on despite being a bit intimidated by them.*

Answer (score 3):

[**Hang in there**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hang%20in%20there%20definition) **-** remain persistent and determined to continue through difficult circumstances.

I have never heard *soldier on* or *march on* in the US (in the past 10 years.)  *Hanging in there* is the phrase I would use for getting through a tough week.

Note: This is more of an informal phrase.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the sixties and seventies: to keep on trucking
Source: personal phrases.

There is even a SONG by Tim McGraw:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyDazBR5riI

Answer (score 0):

A pretty good phrase from the 70's was **keep on keeping on** See Gladys Knight and the Pips https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99NXXt2PzTQ

Answer (score 0):

Two examples widely used are *push on* and *march on* on TedX talks I have listened.  I'm trying to find a video now.